# how i can get these values with matching like this from mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two  tables with  uid. both are same on two tables.

but what happen is on one table uid is like 12/2456. and in another table uid is like 24560.

customer added 0 at the end.

Now i have to retrieve records according to uid from both tables with matching as 2456.

How i can pick up all rows with id only leaving 12 (year) and have to match with another

table?

first table

```
id  uid 

 101 12/2496
```

second table

```
did  uid 
1122 24960
```

now i need answer like

```
id   did   uid 
101  1122  24960
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the two parts looking the same:

```
select * 
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.uid/10 = substr(t1.uid, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select tbl1.id,
tbl2.did,
tbl2.uid
from tbl1 join
tbl2
on
replace(t2.uid,0,'') = substr(t1.uid, 3);
```